# templateUrl angularjs + java

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, angular-ui-router

In which project's folder should I put those template .html files? Neither of those templateUrl codes seem to work.

[image: templates]

imgur link for higher resultion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEJFR.png

nothing loads when clicking those navbar links:
[image: nav]

using controller does not fix problem aswell

```
@Controller
public class RouterController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/shopa/crud", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String getCrud() {
        return "crud.html";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you move your 'views' folder into the 'webapp' folder. It should not be in WEB-INF.

Then try to use

```
templateUrl: '/views/transactions.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the url without the **"/"** prefix will be relative to the main ("index.html") page.

In such a case and as your project structure suggests, the url should be:

```js
//...
.state( 'crud', {
  url: '/browse',
  templateURL : 'views/crud.html'
})
```

You may also need to map all configured routes from client side (with AngularJS) to forward to the main *index.html* page within your controller so that the rest part is left to AngularJS:

```java
@Controller
public class RouterController {
  @RequestMapping( {"/browse", "/history", "/transactions"} )
  public String index() {
    return "forward:index.html";
  }
}
```